# Get modified column ordering for Extjs GridPanel

Tags: javascript, extjs

As part of gridpanel functionality after rendering the gridpanel I can modify the columns ordering by click drag. For example present column ordering is First Name  |  Last Name. But I can click drag first name and put it after Last Name i.e now it will be like   Last Name | First Name.

Now my requirement is something like I want to save the modified order of the column. i.e i want to save the format change which I have made. So does Extjs functionality provide me with modified ordering of the column.

By tejas,

---

visit [mobedio](http://www.mobedio.com),The only public opinion platform for political domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at GridPanel's `stateEvent`, `stateId`, and `stateful` config options in the [API Documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/).

Concerning `stateful`:

> A stateful Component attempts to save
>   state when one of the events listed in
>   the stateEvents configuration fires.

StateEvents for the GridPanel defaults to `stateEvents: ['columnmove', 'columnresize', 'sortchange', 'groupchange']`, so your use case will be handled automatically with 'columnmove'. Keep in mind that you'll have to set up a few config options for this to work, including a state provider (most of the details can be found in the 'stateful' documentation).

Comment: McStretch thanks for the information.. it was really helpful and perfect for my scenario... I think http://examples.extjs.eu/  example of Drag and Drop -> Free Drag with state gives a perfect example of collecting data from cookies and save it... It matches my scenario too.